# Deleting MsgBox and stop macro from running

Tags: vba, if-statement, msgbox

Please help to delete msgbox after if statement is met with vbYes. The code also has to stop running so that the user can free type after msgbox disappears.

Here is my code:

```
Response = MsgBox(“Are you sure you want to change this?”,vbYesNo + vbcritical)
If yourAnswer = vbYes 
Then exit sub
```

Comment: `If Response = vbYes Then Exit Sub`...

Comment: This `“` is not the same as this `"`. Don't copy quotation marks from word, use your keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The user's **Yes** or **No** answer is fed into the **Response** variable.
That variable is what needs to be tested in the **If** statement.
See the code below as an example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Response As Integer

    Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change this?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Change")
    
    If Response = vbYes Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "OK, going to change stuff", vbCritical, "Changing stuff"
        'Your code to make the change goes here instead of another message box.
    End If

End Sub
```